# How to update session id in the auth_user table?

Tags: web2py

I have a problem update my session id to the auth_user database immediately after the user logs in.

Here is the code i have.

```
    def userlogin():
      form = auth.login(onaccept=update_sessionid(auth.user_id))
      return dict(lform=form)

    def update_sessionid(userid):
      x=db(db.auth_user.id==userid).update(sessionid=response.session_id) //I have tried using auth.user_id in the place of userid but in vain
      return 0
```

Please let me know if I am doing some serious mistake. I am not able to see the session id updated to the auth_user database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By default, the auth_user table does not have a "sessionid" field -- did you add it as a custom field? Why do you want to store the session id in the db?

Comment: Anthony, I wanted to somehow maintain the loggedin information of the clients using the server. Once the client is loggedin, subsequent communication to the server is through a series of web server API calls. Hence, I need to maintain the user and corresponding session information. 
I would like to take your advice whether it is preferred to have a separate table to maintain logged in information of the users. How is it generally done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to manually store the login status -- it is already stored in the session (which can be stored in the db rather than the filesystem if you prefer). The session cookie links each request to the associated session. This is all handled automatically by Auth. If you want to get into more detail, it may help to move to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Comment: Thans Anthony, let me try what you said and see whether I could get the desired results.